# How to get partial from another app?

Tags: symfony-1.4

how to `getPartial()` from another app, I need partial in back-end app from front-end app ? I tried to search answer but I did not have success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either create a plugin for this. Or switch the context.

For the latter you can try:

```
    sfContext::switchTo('name-of-other-app');        
    $this->getContext()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial');        
    get_partial('app/module');        
    // dont forget to switch back!
    sfContext::switchTo('name-of-current-app');
```

If you are working in a Controller you can of course use methods like `$this->getPartial()`.

But creating your own plugin is imho a better solution.

Note that switching context will give you a warning about a session already being started. Fabien refused to fix this when still working on Symonfy 1.4.

Comment: And +1 to the plugin option. Much cleaner and better than switching contexts.